# I have an old house that has 2 wire system black wire white wire wrapped in cloth

Tags: attic

It's aluminum wire. I have hot (black) and a white that's supplying 3 other sets of wires. Do I put all 4 black and all 4 white together?? 1 light switch,1 bedroom light , 1 light switch in bathroom that jumps to it's ceiling light and a light in ceiling that jumps to porch light.. but I have 4 sets of 1 black and white . Plz help

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, this is too broad a question for our Q&A format. Please edit it down to a single issue, and give us more information on that issue.

Comment: Yeah, there's a lot of stuff going on there.  Any chance that you have pix of how the wires were arranged when you first opened the box?  Position is everything, certianly color codes don't mean much when all wires are the same two colors.. You also haven't stated where this box is, at the lamp or the switch... Like I say there's a lot to it.

Comment: We would need more information. Where is this located? box in ceiling , wall switch?  you may have switch loops and in that case you do not tie all the same color together. are you sure it's aluminum? Or could it be tinned copper it makes a difference on the method of connecting the wires. I don't remember any cloth insulated aluminum in smaller sizes (#12 & 10) but do remember larger sizes that were cloth

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring please?